# adb shell ping the host does not work

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-ndk-r7

Right now, I want to check whether the android device can connect to another device via the net. I can use the browser to log into the internet. But when I use `adb shell` to connect to the android emulator and use the `ping` command to connect to the host, it fails.

```
 kaiwii@ubuntu:~$ adb shell ping 192.168.145.136 PING 192.168.145.136 (192.168.145.136) 56(84) bytes of data. ^C
```

(192.168.145.136 is the host's ip!)

But when I ping 127.0.0.1, it works. So, I am definitely sure the device supports the ping command. I am just confused why it can not ping the host while I can log into the internet in the browser. What's more, anyone can show any other method to check network ability in android?

Thanks

Comment: just a wild guess - the Phone is in 3g and the PC in WiFi?! Not sure the relation to NDK though ..

Answer (score 6):

adb shell ping -c1 www.google.com

will return below response if device has internet

```
    PING www.google.com (xx.xx.xx.xx) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from (xx.xx.xx.xx): icmp_seq=1 ttl=61 time=25.3 ms

--- www.google.com ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 1 received, 0% packet loss, time 0ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 25.332/25.332/25.332/0.000 ms
```

or else

```
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Answer (score 3):

You're connected to the internet using the phone's data connection, rather than USB via the host computer. Thus, there is no network connectivity between your device and your host. Further, as your host doesn't have a public IP address (it's behind multiple levels of NATs, at least one level being evident from the IP), it is impossible for the device to be able to ping your host via the public internet.

As to checking for network connectivity, you can try the following:

- `ping www.google.com`

The output:

```
 / $ ping -c1 www.google.com
 PING www.google.com (74.125.236.51) 56(84) bytes of data.
 64 bytes from www.google.com (74.125.236.51): icmp_seq=1 ttl=55 time=40.8 ms
 64 bytes from www.google.com (74.125.236.51): icmp_seq=2 ttl=55 time=47.1 ms
 --- www.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 40.850/43.999/47.148/3.149 ms
```

- check network connections: `busybox ifconfig -a`

The output (snipping it a bit):

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 5C:4C:A9:FC:B0:C0 
          inet addr:192.168.2.3  Bcast:192.168.2.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::5e4c:a9ff:fefc:b0c0/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:359 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:275 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:87543 (85.4 KiB)  TX bytes:48382 (47.2 KiB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback 
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:620 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:620 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:74037 (72.3 KiB)  TX bytes:74037 (72.3 KiB)

rmnet0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 9E:43:B5:97:81:B1 
          inet addr:106.197.224.94  Bcast:106.197.224.95  Mask:255.255.255.252
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:2000  Metric:1
          RX packets:54337 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:59160 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:32720935 (31.2 MiB)  TX bytes:8334589 (7.9 MiB)
<snipped value="rmnet1,rmnet2" />
sit0      Link encap:IPv6-in-IPv4 
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
<snipped value="tunl0,usb0" />
```

- The trusty browser and Google combo.

Answer (score 1):

solution for appium:

```java
Map<String, Object> argv = new HashMap<>();
argv.put("command", "dumpsys ");
argv.put("args", Lists.newArrayList("battery"));
String result = ((AppiumDriver) driver).executeScript("mobile: shell", argv).toString();
System.out.println(result);
```